# Ruby - shortest way to get hash value/key inside array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hash

I have

```
 [{{"Chrome"=>["41.0.2272.76"]}=>399}, {{"Firefox"=>["36.0"]}=>7}]
```

How can I get Chrome/41.0.2272.76/399?

Comment: the object is not a valid object..

Answer (score 0):

```
s.map{|item| item.map{|browser, number| browser.map{|k,v| "#{k}/#{v.first}/#{number}"}}}.flatten
```

or

```
s.map do |item| 
  item.map do |browser, number| 
    browser.map do |name,version| 
      "#{name}/#{version.first}/#{number}"
    end
  end
end.flatten
```